# Как расшифровать mysql blob

Tags: php, blob

Получаю значение с базы поля blob например:

```
__ci_last_regenerate|i:1540550888;lang_default|s:209:"{"id":"1","ids":"686ccc3b29dd6b58c67320b0978bfad2","name":"Russian","code":"ru-RU","icon":"flag-icon flag-icon-ru","is_default":"1","status":"1","changed":"2018-09-04 17:58:11","created":"2018-09-04 17:58:11"}";uid|s:2:"45";
```

как его преобразовать в массив php? мне нужно получить последнюю переменную "45", пробовал через unserialize, но он возвращает false

Answer (score 0):

Для функции `unserialize()` у вас указан не верный формат строки, вам нужно разбить эту строку на валидный шаблон, а затем уже использовать `unserialize()`.
Вот примерное решение:

```
$var = explode('|','__ci_last_regenerate|i:1540550888;lang_default|s:209:"{"id":"1","ids":"686ccc3b29dd6b58c67320b0978bfad2","name":"Russian","code":"ru-RU","icon":"flag-icon flag-icon-ru","is_default":"1","status":"1","changed":"2018-09-04 17:58:11","created":"2018-09-04 17:58:11"}";uid|s:2:"45";');
$var = end($array); // для получения последнего элемента
$var_dump(unserialize($var));
```

В итоге получим число `45`.